# How to add a BearerToken to React API Requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, oauth, ruby-on-rails-5

I am a beginner to React. I'm using React to make API requests like so:

```
class CatsApi {
  static createCat(cat) {
    const request = new Request('http://localhost:4300/api/v1/cats', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify(cat)
    });

    return fetch(request).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).catch(error => {
      return error;
    });
  }
```

Meanwhile, I have authentication to my API via react-devise:
https://github.com/timscott/react-devise
Which has a method `getBearerToken` like so: https://github.com/timscott/react-devise/blob/master/src/actions/authTokenStore.js

How do I use getBearerToken to pass the API the token so API requests are authenticated with the token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Authorization` header like:

```
{ 'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}` }
```

Using `fetch` you could try with something like:

```
fetch('http://localhost:4300/api/v1/cats', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        'Accept'       : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        cat : cat_value,
    })
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseData) => { console.log(responseData) })
.catch((error) => { console.log(error) })
.done()
```

Also, it'd be great to see what's the Rails output in the console when you make a request, or the browser console.

Comment: really appreciate the reply. I'm a newbie, would it be possible to show more detailed how I would make this work given the code provided above? I tried what you provided but that didn't work.

Comment: How in the above does ${token} get populated?

Comment: In the network monitor, it's literally sending `Bearer ${token}` --- is token supposed to be populated?

Comment: Yes, you need to get the token wherever the way you're using to get it, it could be stored in the SessionStorage if you're using React.